# How to see list of issues reported by me on GitHub?

Tags: github

I would like to see all the GitHub issues I've reported (across all repositories). How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually you can search for issues **across** repositories by including the `author:$author`. [Here is an example](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=author:pathikrit&s=created&type=Issues) that searches for all issues created by me.

Search for your own issues by putting in your username instead: `https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=author:[username]&s=created&type=Issues`

Comment: This type of search combines both "Issues" and "Pull Requests". Do you know of a way to only see "Issues"?

Answer (score 3):

To take a look at all issues created by you on GitHub (either in your own repositories or in other people's), take a look here: https://github.com/dashboard/issues/created_by

Comment: I see 'Created by you: 0' and 'No issues to show', which isn't right.

Comment: On the top, switch from “Open” to “Closed.”

Comment: Still 'no issues to show', either way

Comment: Please raise a ticket with the GitHub support staff for getting this problem fixed. Here’s the link: https://help.github.com/contact

Answer (score 3):

Rob at GitHub said the ['issues created by you'](https://github.com/dashboard/issues/created_by) page is broken by design:

> Issues you've created in any other repository will only be available at the respective project's issues page.  Our team is aware that this behavior can be confusing, so they are investigating possible changing this in the future.

Comment: The url does not exist anymore.